# Setting up and using liquid

Tags: ruby, installation, liquid

I can't seem to figure out how to get liquid set up on my windows machine.

I installed ruby.  I then used 'gem install liquid' to install liquid.

From here I have no clue how to use liquid in my project.  I'm using gulp, so I don't know if that matters or not

Do I need to create and set up a gem file in my project?  If so, how do I set it up to use liquid?

I'm a complete noob with this and there's absolutely no helpful documentation online.

Comment: all you should need is `require 'liquid'` this will go and find the installed gem and it will be accessible in your project.

Comment: Do I not need to run any gulp tasks for it?

Comment: I am not sure what you intend to do in this project so it is hard for me to help beyond answering your question of "how to use liquid". If you have a more specific question please feel free to ask. Otherwise `require` is how you include ruby gems as a library and then you can access them in your code.